# Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.EnterpriseLibrary.dll for EntLib 5.0.505.0

Tags: .net

Anyone know where i can find the latest version of the Web Application Block that is compiled against or using EntLib 5.0.505.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build this yourself from the source:

> [patterns & practices Web Client Developer Guidance - Downloads](http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/releases/view/43000)

Unzip the file and look under:

`BlocksTrunk\Source\CompositeWeb`

There's a solution file you can open in Visual Studio 2010.